# Elixir Phoenix - Add columns to timestamp

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a phoenix app that utilizes `timestamps` in all of the models. However I want to extend timestamps so that whenever I include `timestamps` in a model it adds the following fields:

```
created_at     (utc datetime)
updated_at     (utc datetime)
created_at_utc (utc timestamp of created_at field)
updated_at_utc (utc timestamp of updated_at field)
```

How can I extend the timestamps function (or generate a new one) which automatically generates these fields?

**UPDATE**
As suggested in the answers I've attempted to extend the Ecto.Schema and Ecto.Migrations modules in my helper `db_helpers.ex` as seen below:

```
defmodule Extension do
  defmacro extends(module) do
    module    = Macro.expand(module, __CALLER__)
    functions = module.__info__(:functions)

    signatures = Enum.map functions, fn { name, arity } ->
      args = Enum.map 0..arity, fn(i) ->
        { String.to_atom(<< ?x, ?A + i >>), [], nil }
      end

      { name, [], tl(args) }
    end

    quote do
      defdelegate unquote(signatures), to: unquote(module)
      defoverridable unquote(functions)
    end
  end
end


defmodule Ecto.Schema do
    import Extension

    extends Ecto.Schema

    @doc """
      Generates `:inserted_at` and `:updated_at` timestamp fields.
      The fields generated by this macro will automatically be set to
      the current time when inserting and updating values in a repository.
      ## Options
        * `:type` - the timestamps type, defaults to `:naive_datetime`.
        * `:type_utc` - the utc timestamps type, defaults to `:utc_datetime`.
        * `:usec` - sets whether microseconds are used in timestamps.
          Microseconds will be 0 if false. Defaults to true.
        * `:created_at` - the name of the column for insertion times or `false`
        * `:updated_at` - the name of the column for update times or `false`
        * `:created_at_utc` - the name of the column for utc insertion times or `false`
        * `:updated_at_utc` - the name of the column for utc update times or `false`
        * `:autogenerate` - a module-function-args tuple used for generating
          both `inserted_at` and `updated_at` timestamps
      All options can be pre-configured by setting `@timestamps_opts`.
  """
  defmacro timestamps(opts \\ []) do
    quote bind_quoted: binding() do
      timestamps =
        [created_at: :created_at, updated_at: :updated_at,
         created_at_utc: :created_at_utc, inserted_at_utc: :inserted_at_utc,
         type: :naive_datetime, type_utc: :utc_datetime,
         usec: true]
        |> Keyword.merge(@timestamps_opts)
        |> Keyword.merge(opts)

      type      = Keyword.fetch!(timestamps, :type)
      type_utc      = Keyword.fetch!(timestamps, :type_utc)
      precision = if Keyword.fetch!(timestamps, :usec), do: :microseconds, else: :seconds
      autogen   = timestamps[:autogenerate] || {Ecto.Schema, :__timestamps__, [type, precision]}

      if created_at = Keyword.fetch!(timestamps, :created_at) do
        Ecto.Schema.field(created_at, type, [])
        Module.put_attribute(__MODULE__, :ecto_autogenerate, {created_at, autogen})
      end

      if updated_at = Keyword.fetch!(timestamps, :updated_at) do
        Ecto.Schema.field(updated_at, type, [])
        Module.put_attribute(__MODULE__, :ecto_autogenerate, {updated_at, autogen})
        Module.put_attribute(__MODULE__, :ecto_autoupdate, {updated_at, autogen})
      end

      if created_at_utc = Keyword.fetch!(timestamps, :created_at_utc) do
        Ecto.Schema.field(created_at_utc, type, [])
        Module.put_attribute(__MODULE__, :ecto_autogenerate, {created_at_utc, autogen})
      end

      if updated_at_utc = Keyword.fetch!(timestamps, :updated_at_utc) do
        Ecto.Schema.field(updated_at_utc, type, [])
        Module.put_attribute(__MODULE__, :ecto_autogenerate, {updated_at_utc, autogen})
        Module.put_attribute(__MODULE__, :ecto_autoupdate, {updated_at_utc, autogen})
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Ecto.Migration do
  import Extension

  extends Ecto.Migration

  @doc """
      Adds `:created_at` and `:updated_at` timestamps columns.
      Those columns are of `:naive_datetime` type, and by default
      cannot be null. `opts` can be given to customize the generated
      fields.
      ## Options
        * `:created_at` -  the name of the column for insertion times, providing `false` disables column
        * `:updated_at` - the name of the column for update times, providing `false` disables column
        * `:created_at_utc` -  the name of the column for utc insertion times, providing `false` disables column
        * `:updated_at_utc` - the name of the column for utc update times, providing `false` disables column
        * `:type` - column type, defaults to `:naive_datetime`
        * `:type_utc` - column type for utc, defaults to `:utc_datetime`
  """
  def timestamps(opts \\ []) do
    opts = Keyword.put_new(opts, :null, false)

    {type, opts} = Keyword.pop(opts, :type, :naive_datetime)
    {type_utc, opts} = Keyword.pop(opts, :type_utc, :utc_datetime)
    {created_at, opts} = Keyword.pop(opts, :created_at, :created_at)
    {updated_at, opts} = Keyword.pop(opts, :updated_at, :updated_at)
    {created_at_utc, opts} = Keyword.pop(opts, :created_at_utc, :created_at_utc)
    {updated_at_utc, opts} = Keyword.pop(opts, :updated_at_utc, :updated_at_utc)

    if created_at != false, do: add(created_at, type, opts)
    if updated_at != false, do: add(updated_at, type, opts)
    if created_at_utc != false, do: add(created_at_utc, type_utc, opts)
    if updated_at_utc != false, do: add(updated_at_utc, type_utc, opts)
  end
end
```

However, when I try to run `mix ecto.migrate` I am getting the following error:

```
== Compilation error on file web/models/accounts.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/models/accounts.ex:4: undefined function schema/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

Shouldn't the `extends` macro make it so that all methods are available. Note that the `Extension` module comes from here: https://gist.github.com/pavlos/c86858290743b4d4fed9

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**1**. Consider **extending**  [timestamps](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/schema.ex#L465)  from `Ecto.Schema` and function [timestamps](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/migration.ex#L672) function from `Ecto.Migration` in your helper, that you will import in your models and migrations. Try to implement your columns the same way they are implemented in the source code.

This approach might:

- takes more time, because of digging and studying source code
- be more beneficial because of better knowledge of source code
- be harder to implement and ensure that you won't make mistakes

**2**. Use **new** function or macro from helpers instead of extending functionality of `timestamps`. It will:

- takes less time and effort
- be easier to implement

**Remember** that you want to have these fields not only in your models, but in your database, which means you will have to add them in your migrations or prepare a script that will add them based on the current values from database.

Comment: I've tried extending the schema and migration as suggested, but am now getting some other issues as mentioned in the update. Any thoughts?

Comment: Drop the idea of extending :) Use 2. approach, it will be faster and more safe for you that you won't break anything.